# simple user input validation in winforms

Tags: .net, winforms

I want to implement simple validation of user input inside my form.

I have errorProvider1 and txtCode form field which I want to validate. So I've put following

```
private void txtCode_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtCode.Text == "")
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtCode, "Field cannot be empty");
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtCode,"");
            }

        }
```

I don't know how to call this method `txtCode_Validating` when user click on Ok button?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
   {
    // Set focus on control
    control.Focus();
    // Validate causes the control's Validating event to be fired,
    // if CausesValidation is True
    if (!Validate())
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        return;
    }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps